# Approach for storing temporary and permanent address in rdbms

Tags: mysql, rdbms

We need to store user's temporary and permanent address in database.I am planning to create only one table address in database and will use same table for both temporary and permanent address.Is there any better approach ?
 Also there is condition -temporary address field can be null like city,state but these fields can't be null for permanent address.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a column to your `address` table showing the address type, temporary, or permanent. You could also define an alternate address type.

Then you can have multiple addresses for each user.

You may also wish to add a `address_good_until` column of type `DATE`. You can then make your temporary addresses expire. If that column is `NULL` it means the address is permanent.

Comment: That's seems pretty good,but for temporary address null values are allowed in database (like i can have null for city) and for permanent address null values are not allowed (i can't have null for city),which restrict me to use same table.is there any approach i can go for  ?